# Some [font-size] classes aren't working in Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind v3.1.7 and most of the classes are seem to be working fine. However, some of the font size classes aren't working. For example:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgq8d.jpg) in the screenshot, the highlighted `h3` element has 3 classes: `text-4xl` `text-primary-black2` `font-bold`. Last 2 classes are seem to be working fine as shown in the image, however the font size one does not work. I have tried to replace `text-4xl` with `text-[36px]` and it still did not work. [click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezizf.jpg)

The only font size class that works is `text-base` as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKSdw.jpg).

I've checked the spelling and other things and they all seem to look fine and I did not find any errors. What I think the problem is that somehow the font size classes aren't overlapping default tailwind classes. This is because when I changed the font size from the css file, it changed. And even when I added `style="font-size: 36px;"` in the same `h3` element, it worked.

Not sure how to fix this thing out. I really need to finish this project as soon as possible so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you purging unused classes when compiling to output.css?

Comment: How'd you know if you're purging unused classes? But I just added the text-4xl class in output.css after your comment. And it seems to be working now. I am just not sure if its the right way to fix this error

Comment: Tailwind 3, unlike Tailwind 2, will purge unused classes. Make sure to re-run the npm command or whatever command you need for re-building the tailwind css. On laravel I use `npm run production` or `npm run prod`, you'll probably need to use a similar command depending on the way you're using tailwind.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! It looks like rebuilding tailwind solved the problem. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey Kevin. You had better post this great comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the issue, there was a problem with my content:[] tailwind.config.js file, components folder path was set wrong previously, So, I changed its path and it worked.

The **content property** is mainly responsible for compiling the tailwind classes for project files
Make sure your content values contain the right path for the components you wanna render tailwindcss classes

Wrong path:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}", './components/**/*.jsx'
```

Right Path:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}", './src/components/**/*.jsx'
```